# Syntax Error Help

Tags: sql-server, syntax

I have this script that works just fine but when I change the directory paths it seems to get this syntax error "unclosed quotation mark after the character string" I have looked over this for hours and can't fine the unclosed quotation mark and any other issues that would cause this.

```
DECLARE @db VARCHAR(50), 
@sql NVARCHAR(400),
@country varchar(100)
DECLARE barcardi cursor for 
select [ProjectDB] from [DBA].[dbo].[BacardiExport] order by [Country] asc
open barcardi 
fetch next from barcardi into @db
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
        set @country = (select country from [DBA].[dbo].[BacardiExport] where [ProjectDB] = @db)
        set @sql = 'BACKUP DATABASE ['+@db+'] TO  DISK = N''D:\ConfirmitN02BackupNew\BacardiProjectBackup\Bacardi_'+@country+'_'+@db+'.bak'' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10'
        exec sp_executesql @sql
        --print @sql

        set @country = (select country from [DBA].[dbo].[BacardiExport] where [ProjectDB] = @db)
        set @sql = 'RESTORE DATABASE [Bacardi_'+@country+'_'+@db+'] FROM  DISK = N''D:\ConfirmitN02BackupNew\BacardiProjectBackup\Bacardi_'+@country+'_'+@db+'.bak'' WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'''+@db+'_dat'' TO N''D:\ConfirmitN02-MDF\confirmit_sql_data\Bacardi_'+@country+'_'+@db+'.mdf'',  MOVE N'''+@db+'_log'' TO N''D:\ConfirmitN02-LDF\confirmit_sql_log\Bacardi_'+@country+'_'+@db+'.ldf'',  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5'
        exec sp_executesql @sql
        --print @sql

        set @country = (select country from [DBA].[dbo].[BacardiExport] where [ProjectDB] = @db)
        set @sql = 'UPDATE [DBA].[dbo].[BacardiExport] set [CopyProjectDB] =  ''Bacardi_'+@country+'_'+@db+''' where [ProjectDB] = '''+ @db +''''
        exec sp_executesql @sql
        --print @sql

        update [DBA].[dbo].[BacardiExport] set [Copied] = 1 where [ProjectDB] = @db
        update [DBA].[dbo].[BacardiExport] set [ProcessDate] = getdate() where [ProjectDB] = @db

    fetch next from barcardi into @db
    end
close barcardi
deallocate barcardi
```

Here is a bit of the output.

> SSIS package "D:\ConfirmitN02BackupNew\Bacardi\DataExport2\DataExport2\Package.dtsx" starting.
>   Error: 0xC002F210 at Copy Bacardi Databses, Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "DECLARE @db VARCHAR(50), 
>   @sql NVARCHAR(400),
>   @c..." failed with the following error: "Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'D:\ConfirmitN02-LDF\confirmit_sql_log\Bacardi_Belgium_survey_p1622247398.ld'.
>   Incorrect syntax near 'D:\ConfirmitN02-LDF\confirmit_sql_log\Bacardi_Belgium_survey_p1622247398.ld'.
>   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'D:\ConfirmitN02-LDF\confirmit_sql_log\Bacardi_Germany_survey_p1622259397.ld'.
>   Incorrect syntax near 'D:\ConfirmitN02-LDF\confirmit_sql_log\Bacardi_Germany_survey_p1622259397.ld'.
>   'NOUN' is not a recognized RESTORE option.
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.
>   11 percent processed.
>   20 percent processed.
>   30 percent processed.
>   40 percent processed.
>   50 percent processed.
>   60 percent processed.
>   70 percent processed.
>   80 percent processed.
>   90 percent processed.
>   Processed 11584 pages for database 'survey_p1622247398', file 'survey_p1622247398_dat' on file 1.
>   100 percent processed.
>   Processed 5 pages for database 'survey_p1622247398', file 'survey_p1622247398_log' on file 1.
>   BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 11589 pages in 1.909 seconds (47.425 MB/sec).
>   BACKUP DATABASE [survey_p1622247398] TO  DISK = N'D:\ConfirmitN02BackupNew\BacardiProjectBackup\Bacardi_Belgium_survey_p1622247398.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
>   RESTORE DATABASE [Bacardi_Belgium_survey_p1622247398] FROM  DISK = N'D:\ConfirmitN02BackupNew\BacardiProjectBackup\Bacardi_Belgium_survey_p1622247398.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'survey_p1622247398_dat' TO N'D:\ConfirmitN02-MDF\confirmit_sql_data\Bacardi_Belgium_survey_p1622247398.mdf',  MOVE N'survey_p1622247398_log' TO N'D:\ConfirmitN02-LDF\confirmit_sql_log\Bacardi_Belgium_survey_p1622247398.ld
>   UPDATE [DBA].[dbo].[BacardiExport] set [CopyProjectDB] =  'Bacardi_Belgium_survey_p1622247398' where [ProjectDB] = 'survey_p1622247398'

Comment: NOUN instead of NOUNLOAD definitely looks like truncation to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Glad you got the truncation issue figured out, but may I offer an alternative that won't be prone to that, eliminates the need for cursor scaffolding, etc.?

```
DECLARE @src nvarchar(max) = N'', @sql nvarchar(max) = N'';

SELECT @src = N'
  BACKUP DATABASE $qdb$ TO  DISK 
  = N''D:\ConfirmitN02BackupNew\BacardiProjectBackup\Bacardi_$c$_$db$.bak''
   WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10;

  RESTORE DATABASE [Bacardi_$c$_$db$] FROM DISK 
  = N''D:\ConfirmitN02BackupNew\BacardiProjectBackup\Bacardi_$c$_$db$.bak'' 
   WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N''$db$_dat'' 
   TO N''D:\ConfirmitN02-MDF\confirmit_sql_data\Bacardi_$c$_$db$.mdf'',
   MOVE N''$db$_log'' TO N''D:\ConfirmitN02-LDF\confirmit_sql_log\Bacardi_$c$_$db$.ldf'',
   NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5;

  UPDATE [DBA].[dbo].[BacardiExport] set [CopyProjectDB] = ''Bacardi_$c$_$db$'',
    Copied = 1, ProcessDate = GETDATE() where [ProjectDB] = ''$db$'';';

SELECT @sql += REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@src,   
  N'$c$',country),N'$db$',ProjectDB),N'$qdb$',QUOTENAME(ProjectDB))
FROM DBA.dbo.BacardiExport;

PRINT @sql; -- this may not display everything, depending on how many rows
-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```